# PostgreSQL JDBC prepared statement query string with single quotes giving error

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run a query using JDBC but i'm having difficulty injecting values into the prepared statement. Here is a sample of what I was doing:

```
String queryString = "... WHERE location <@ box '((?, ?),(?, ?))' ..."
PreparedStatement ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
ps.setDouble(1, x1);
ps.setDouble(2, y1);
ps.setDouble(3, x2);
ps.setDouble(4, y2);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Which gives me this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0
```

I think it thinks that the values in the single quotes are string literals and so it doesn't see the ? as parameters to inject. I've tried various other

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Or rather what else I should be looking to do?

Comment: have you tried creating a string of the coordinates and adding that as a single parameter (with no quotes around it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [geometric type conversion functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE) to construct a box without having to go through a string:

```
... WHERE location <@ box(point(?, ?), point(?, ?)) ...
```

Comment: Hmmm when i do this i get another error:


```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: there is no parameter $1
```